# Visual Studio Code error - 'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Setup:
Windows 7 64 bit
Visual Studio Code, version 1.30.0
Dotnet version: 2.2.101

I am at the beginning of trying to learn how to program with C# and I have hit a snag.

I am attempting to follow the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code
and I am not getting past the start of it.

The only wrinkle I can think of is that I have installed Visual Studio on my D: drive. 
I have checked my environmental variables and I see that if I go into my system variables under the path variables I see C:\program files\dotnet.

Also if I am in the interactive terminal in Visual Studio I can go to the folder location of the dotnet.exe, type in the terminal >dotnet --version
and a dotnet version shows on my terminal.

Do I need to muck with my environment variables or move my dotnet.exe file to the D drive also to get this puppy goin?

Comment: it could be because that VS Code is opened before you install DotNet Core? So VS Code doesn’t know how to locate dotnet.exe.

Comment: Well I don't know if this was totally it, but I restarted my computer and the path variable seems to work now.

Comment: Very probable, because when a process (like VSCode) is started, it makes its own copy of the PATH environment variable from the system, and the value doesn’t get refreshed until the process is restarted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you need to download and install `.NET Core SDK`

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: if dotnet --version returns error then you need to set it into PATH under system environment variables. Also after installation you need to restart your host computer

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the environment variable C:\program files\dotnet is under the Path variable

Comment: the problem is either not properly installed or PATH variable is not set. check it carefully. It cannot be anything else. Also check that you installed SDK rather than runtime version

Comment: I am commenting that you have answered my question, but after a restart I can now go into the Visual Studio Terminal type >dotnet --version and now I get a response >2.2.101  which is what I expect.

Comment: For future readers, I just restart after install sdk package. And now it works!

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers mention, I needed to first install `.NET`.
But after install and restart, the problem persisted for me.

The final fix for me was to click the "Kill Terminal" button and then open a new one.
Apparently the terminal session can survive a restart.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue,
Problem statement:- I have installed dotnet core sdk in my sys, even than when I hit dotnet in command prompt I was getting ,

```
dotnet-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external
```

Solution :- I have added dotnet path to advanced system settings-> Environment variables-> user variables.
Path = "C:\Program Files\dotnet"
refer the image
[error solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpY2e.png)

Answer (score 1):

it could be because, maybe you haven't installed the `dotnet core` yet, which seems to be required prior to installing the asp.net core spa template. To check if you have installed the `.net core` in your machine or not, check if this exists

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
```

or just type following in `command prompt`

```
dotnet --version
```

or You need to install `.NET SDK` separately. You can `download` and install it [from here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)

Answer (score 1):

I hit install from the installation directory by double-clicking the download and by selecting `Repair`. (There were two other options `Uninstall` and `Cancel`).

After repair, I just typed `dotnet --version` at the cmd prompt and got the version displayed.

My environment is Windows 10 on AMD64 processor.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure the `C# extention` in `VSCode` is uninstalled
- Kill any `VSCode` process using the `Task Manager` (ctrl+shift+esc in Windows)
- Install the `dotnet SDK` from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download
- Locate your `dotnet` using `where.exe dotnet` command in a `cmd`
- Add the address that you get to the system `path`. follow [this link](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Under%20the%20%E2%80%9CSystem%20Variables%E2%80%9D%20section,also%20edit%20or%20reorder%20them.)
- Reboot your device
- In `VSCode`, install `C# extention`
- In Unity -> edit -> preferences -> external tools, set `External Script Editor` to `Visual Studio Code`
- Hit the `Regenerate Project Files` button
- Now open a script file from inside Unity and see if it's fixed

In most cases, you don't need to do all the steps. It depends on which part is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you close `VSCode` after closing the terminal, the problem will be fixed. But you need to make sure .net is installed. If you are a Windows user, you can learn the installed version with `dotnet --version` in cmd or powershell.

If there is no version information, .net may not be installed on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you've installed `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022` (or any given year/version). Here's the link to it: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ In case the link breaks, use some search engine to look for it.

That should install the dotnet CLI.

> These Build Tools allow you to build Visual Studio projects from a command-line interface. Supported projects include: ASP.NET, Azure, C++ desktop, ClickOnce, containers, .NET Core, .NET Desktop, Node.js, Office and SharePoint, Python, TypeScript, Unit Tests, UWP, WCF, and Xamarin. Use of this tool requires a valid Visual Studio license, unless you are building open-source dependencies for your project. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lSHW.png))

In my system, after the installation, I've got this available:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, i had the same problem and also i had plenty of extensions, so i defaulted the vsCode.
To do that, you can press win+R, type %appdata% go to code\user and delete the `settings.json`.
After that go to %USERPROFILE% (by pressing win+R), then .vscode\extensions, select all the extensions and delete them.

REMINDER: this will make vscode as you have installed for the first time, so beware that your extensions will be gone, so backup them or remember which you use in order to appropriately download them back.

Hope this help people with the same problem.