# Environmental variables not working (Windows 11)

Tags: .net, windows, cmd, path

I was trying to setup the .NET SDK as I've started learning Unity.

The problem is I can't seem to be able to use `dotnet` in the CMD. I checked my path to see if the .NET installer included it and it did. Running `echo %PATH%` in CMD includes `C:\Program Files\dotnet\;`.

Still I get this error when running 'dotnet' or any dotnet command in CMD:

```
'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When I open a terminal in the `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` directory and run 'dotnet' everything works as expected.

It's as if Windows ignores my path. I'm lost and can't find any way to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code error - 'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852594/visual-studio-code-error-dotnet-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external)

Comment: As I said, I can run "dotnet" directly from the install directory. The .NET Core is installed (even reinstalled and even multiple versions besides the latest).

Comment: Did you open a new terminal after updating your PATH-variable? Note if you are using Visual Studio Code that Visual Studio Code may reuse the same terminal session even after closing.

Comment: Yes, reopened the terminal, restared my pc. Did all the obvious solutions, but sadly none of them worked. Hence why I resorted to stack overflow :(.

Comment: Maybe try `where.exe dotnet` to make sure that Windows doesn't find it at all

Comment: `C:\Users\Samuel>where.exe dotnet
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe` It seems to find it. Does this indicate the nature of the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249720/discussion-between-samu-242-and-ascendise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Windows ignored my user environment variables. Adding `C:\Program Files\dotnet\;` to my system environment variables instead of my user environment variables seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have to set path variables manually, this isn't 1999. The installer should handle all of this for you. But if you add user variables, restart your console. And/or log out and back in after adding variables.

Comment: It did set it automatically, problem was that it had put '; C:\Program files\dotnet\' instead of 'C:\Program files\dotnet\'. For some reason there was a semicolon at the start of that line, that's why he couldn't handle it.

Comment: The semicolon should not be a problem, but a leading space is…

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you don't make the same mistake as me. My mistake was that instead of editing the PATH environment variable, I was creating a new environment variable. However, I didn't need to create a new environment variable, I needed to add to the existing environment variable named PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this confused me too. Let's say you want to add `C:\Foo` to your path, and you have this for your current Path:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

You might be thinking you can select *Path*, click *Edit...*, then *Edit* again and tack on `;C:\Foo` like:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Foo`

Right?

**WRONG!**

In the *Edit environment variable* dialog, click `New` and add it as a new entry. When you close the dialog, and will concatenate the path segments.

Comment: This does not answer the question, the OP didn't want to create a `New` variable. What you have posted as **WRONG** is exactly how you add something to your User 'Path' variable, and therefore correct.